# Twilight Zelda Guardian Puzzle : TIKZ Graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've asked another question over at math.stackexchange.com (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245680/twilight-zelda-guardian-puzzle-shortest-path-proof)) and I feel that I will want to make a TIKZ node grid of the problem so I can display the answer connected with arrows. I'm using www.overleaf.com right now, and I'm having a bit of trouble. I just want something simple that color the guardian and Link differently and allows for the placement of half-arrows.

HERE IS MY AUTO-UPDATING CODE (as of April 21, 2015 @ 8:15 PM America/Los_Angeles): https://www.overleaf.com/2588660pvgwfg

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,
  thick,main node/.style={circle,fill=#1!20,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]


  \node[main node=white] (1) {};
  \node[main node=white] (2) [below of=1] {};
  \node[main node=white] (3) [below of=2] {};
  \node[main node=white] (4) [right of=1] {};
  \node[main node=black] (5) [below of=4] {$\bigoplus$};
  \node[main node=white] (6) [below of=5] {};
  \node[main node=white] (7) [below of=6] {};
  \node[main node=white] (8) [below of=7] {};
  \node[main node=red] (9) [right of=5] {$\mathscr{G}_{\text{\textbullet}}$}; %09%
  \node[main node=white] (10) [right of=6] {};
  \node[main node=green] (11) [right of=7] {$\mathscr{L}$}; %11%
  \node[main node=white] (12) [right of=8] {};
  \node[main node=red] (13) [below of=12] {$\mathscr{G}_{\text{\textopenbullet}}$}; %13%
  \node[main node=black] (15) [right  of=9] {$\bigoplus$};
  \node[main node=white] (14) [above of=15] {};
  \node[main node=white] (16) [right of=10] {};
  \node[main node=white] (17) [right  of=11] {};
  \node[main node=white] (18) [right  of=12] {};
  \node[main node=white] (19) [right  of=14] {};
  \node[main node=white] (20) [right  of=15] {};
  \node[main node=white] (21) [right  of=16] {};

  %E/S/N/N/N/W/W/S/S/S/E/N/%

  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]

    %LINK%
    (11) edge node [above] {1} (17)
    (17) edge [bend right] node [left] {2} (18)
    (18) edge [bend right] node [right] {3} (17)
    (17) edge node [right] {4} (16)
    (16) edge node [right] {5} (15)
    (15) edge node [above] {6} (9)
    (9) edge node [above] {7} (5)
    (5) edge node [left] {8} (6)
    (6) edge node [left] {9} (7)
    (7) edge node [left] {10} (8)
    (8) edge node [above] {11} (12)
    (12) edge node [right] {12} (11)
    %GUARDIAN BOTTOM%
    (13) edge [loop right, color=red, very thick] node {1} (13)
    (13) edge [loop below, color=red, very thick] node {2} (13)
    (13) edge [color=red, very thick] node [left] {3} (12)
    (12) edge [bend left, color=red, very thick] node [left] {4} (11)
    (11) edge [color=red, very thick] node [left] {5} (10)
    (10) edge [color=red, very thick] node [above] {6} (6)
    (6) edge [color=red, very thick] node [above] {7} (3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

How can I change the node colors (see [ORIGINAL](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/graph/)) and get a half-arrow?

Comment: How can I color the nodes differently?

Comment: You might want to look at the `chains` library, by the way, depending on exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Using what I've got already, how can I achieve something like `right above` I get an error using this literally.

Comment: `above right` doesn't actually place the node in the right position.

Comment: I've cleared up some comments here. I'm not sure what 'auto-updating' code is, but as it stands that does not influence the question as we have a solid example.

Comment: So... what is the problem???

Comment: How can I get a half arrow? Half the length.

Comment: Where should a half arrow go to and from?

Comment: This is still not clear to me. Is your current question related to the specific layout of your example or the title of this post? And did you try any keyword other than **half**? For instance, **shorten arrow**?